# How to prevent full stack traces in PHP error log when Xdebug is active without disabling Xdebug?

Tags: php, xdebug

So far I haven't found any way to disable the full stack traces in the PHP error log without disabling Xdebug itself. (using `xdebug_disable();`) But I want to use Xdebug to its fullest potential, just with a cleaner, less bloated error log.

It might not even be possible, but I wanted to make sure there are no other possibilities like redirecting Xdebugs stack trace to some other file (which I also tried but without success) or something I haven't thought about.

Comment: Have a look at the xdebug config options: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings there should be one that controlls the trace depth aor format

Comment: @Auris tried several configurations, there was no option to disable stack trace logging or redirecting the trace log somewhere else except for disabling xdebug itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the Xdebug documentation and trying all formatting options and trying to redirect the Xdebug logs, it seems that there is no true solution for this except disabling Xdebug when not needed during development.

Since I am developing a dockerized application I changed the Dockerfile to use an ENV that enables or disables Xdebug.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.0.31-apache-stretch
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
RUN echo 'xdebug.default_enable=${XDEBUG}' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=${XDEBUG}' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=${XDEBUG}' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=0' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Run the container built with above Dockerfile with

- Xdebug enabled (stack trace enabled in logs) by using `--env XDEBUG=1` or
- Xdebug disabled (no stack trace in logs) by `--env XDEBUG=0`

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  php-container:
    build:
      context: . #Path to Dockerfile
    environment:
      XDEBUG: 0 #1 enables Xdebug
    volumes:
      - "./src:/var/www/html/"
```